# equation of plane in $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: linear-algebra

i have this question

what is the equation of  An affine subspace of dimension 2 in  $\mathbb{R}^4$ ?

for example $\{(x_1;x_2,x_3,x_4\}|x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=0$ is it  An affine subspace of dimension 2 in $\mathbb{R}^4$

thanks for every answer

Comment: What do you mean by "plane"? An affine subspace of dimension $2$, or an affine subspace of codimension $1$ (also known as hyperplane)?

Comment: edited ;) .....

Comment: yOu coULd hAve wrITten it properly, sInce you were at It.

Answer (score 1):

$\{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4):x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=0\}$
is an affine hyperplane (i.e. a subspace of dimension $3$) in $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Answer (score 1):

Each linear equation reduces the dimension of the subspace by $1$.  If you want a two dimensional subspace of $\Bbb R^4$ you need two equations, just like it takes two equations to specify a line in $\Bbb R^3$.  You could take $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=0, x_1=0$ for example.  More simply, you could take $x_1=0,x_2=0$.  Now you have the plane consisting of all points of the form $(0,0,x_3,x_4)$